# Socket In TIME_WAIT on Client when exit, but not on restart

Tags: windows, linux-networking, tcp

Linux Server (port 7000)

Windows Client (port 8585)

**Scenario 1: Client Restart**

- Restart on client
- Server socket read returns -1, gets errno 104, Connection reset by peer
- Server closes its socket connection to the client
- Client calls close on its socket
- Client restarts and is able to connect right away to Server

**Scenario 2: Client Exit**

- Exit on client
- Server socket read returns 0, gets errno 11, Resource temporarily unavailable
- Server closes its socket connection to the client
- Client calls close on its socket
- Client netstat shows

  `TCP   Client IP:8585   Server:7000   TIME_WAIT InHost`

**What is causing the server socket read to return 0 on restart, and not -1 with errno 104?**

The client is calling the shutdown/close on the windows socket for both restart/exit. I understand what the TIME_WAIT state is for TCP. But I don't understand what is causing this TIME_WAIT.

*Wireshark Restart*: There is a TCP [RST, ACK] from the Server

*Wireshark Exit*: There is a TCP [FIN, ACK] from the Server

Not sure why they would differ if I am calling the same close method for the client socket.

Comment: Already answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states  and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230227/time-wait-from-netstat

Comment: Why can i reconnect to the server right away on a restart. But when i exit and then reopen the client, it takes 2 minutes to connect? Doesn't make sense. I should have the same behavior for both and I don't.